# raw h.264 packet capture and playing in VLC

Tags: video, networking, vlc, h.264, rtp

I am capturing packets off the network from a video conference HDX. The video is sent in RTP and is encoded in H264.

I am trying to capture these packets and generate a video file. I wrote raw H264 data from the packets to disk and i am trying to play it in VLC.

VLC just shows a green box.

Am i being too naive in my approach with data writing or should am I wrong in assuming that VLC should play this file?

Anyone have any experience in such things?

Answer (score 2):

Another option on linux would be to create a [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) pipeline that captures rtp, decodes using ffmpeg and displays on screen using ximageview.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a raw dump of the packets into a file.

The file format is simply the packets appended one after the other with nothing else in between. The file name should be `.dump` and once you do that, VLC should replay the video correctly.  I just had to do this and this is what worked for me.